# Phantom Bottom Border Around Script

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to find the source of a bottom border in my small personal website. I have a processing sketch in the background that I'm trying to stretch to the full size of the page. I also want my body element to render from top to bottom.

This is my issue:

[image: Bad Border]

I made the html background a garish yellow for high-visibility.

I have a div holding the sketch for absolute positioning with no margin and no padding.

Inspect element doesn't reveal where the space is coming from and I've tested it in FF and in Safari.

Here is the page: [My Personal Page (http://asperw.me)](http://asperw.me)

My research on this question turns up results where top margins had collapsed or there was a random top padding but I'm fairly sure neither of those my culprit.

Thank you.

Edit: I should mention that I don't think the problem is with the sketch as the height of it is equal to the height of the body element. You can also right-click and view image and it doesn't have the bottom border there.

Comment: `#background-canvas { display:block; }` ... hmm, worked once! actually, works "eventually" - not seen anything like that before!

Comment: I just tried it and it worked! What do you mean by "eventually"? Also why would that work when I'm using position absolute?

Comment: I have no clue!  I would've posted that as an answer if I knew why

Comment: I think canvas is inline block. Line height 0 and font size 0 would be an alternative